# React: State becomes undefined after reducer function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a complex nested object on which I have to make some changes. So I decided to use the useReducer hook. I created the reducer function and whenever I try to append an array within the nested object it makes the whole state undefined.

I tried logging out the data and I found out that it runs twice because of the strict mode. It could log out the state value with two added values instead of one, but it immediately changed to undefined.

Here is my code:

*Create.js*

```
const [sections, sectionsDispatch] = useReducer(
  sectionsReducer,
  defaultSections
);
```

*sectionsReducer.js* The error happens here in the new_data case

```
export default function sectionsReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "swap_sections": {
      return swap_sections(
        state,
        action.data.startIndex,
        action.data.destinationIndex
      );
    }
    case "new_data": {
      return new_data(state, action.data.currentSectionId, action.data.newData);
    }
    case "swap_data": {
      return swap_data(
        state,
        action.data.currentSectionId,
        action.data.startIndex,
        action.data.destinationIndex
      );
    }

    default:
      break;
  }
}

function new_data(state, currentSectionId, newData) {
  const keys = findById(state, currentSectionId).data.map((data) => data.id);
  const id = keys.length > 0 ? Math.max(...keys) + 1 : 1;
  let newSections = [...state];
  const currentNewSection = findById(newSections, currentSectionId);
  currentNewSection.data = [
    ...currentNewSection.data, newData(id)];
  return newSections;
}
```

*Other.js*

```
sectionsDispatch({
   type: "new_data",
   data: {
     currentSectionId: currentSectionId,
     newData: (id) => {
       return {
         id: id,
         data: new EducationModel(),
         deleted: false,
         index: id,
       };
     },
   },
 });
```

I used a useEffect hook to log out the `sections` state. It first logged out the state with two added values. And immediately after it logged out undefined.

I also tried without strict mode and it produced the same error. I also tired removing the append part of the `new_data` function so it resulted the following code:

```
  const keys = findById(state, currentSectionId).data.map((data) => data.id);
  const id = keys.length > 0 ? Math.max(...keys) + 1 : 1;
  let newSections = [...state];
  const currentNewSection = findById(newSections, currentSectionId);
  currentNewSection.data = [...currentNewSection.data];
  return newSections;
}
```

It didn't have any error, but It also didn't append the array as expected. So I think my problem is somewhere here. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: Do you have any working examples or code snippet link to look at?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The whole project is a few thousand lines of code and I'm not allowed to make it public

Comment: could you paste findById logic?

Comment: Can you make a minimum reproducible example at least and yes what is findById is it running synchronously or async?

Comment: Here is the findById function:
function findById(sections, id) {
  return sections.find((section) => {
    return section.id === id;
  });
}

And about the example you asked, I have to ask around, how much I'm able to share so it will take some time

Comment: are you sure that currentSectionId exists in the currentState? could you console.log it?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it logged out just fine.

Comment: could you paste currentNewSection.data log and newData(id)?

Comment: I put the logs right before the return and newData(id) logged out this object twice: {id: 1, data: Model, deleted: false, index: 1} and the currentNewSection.data logged out a list twice with two of these objects with ids 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your `new_data` function returns `newSections`, but it looks like you *want* it to return `currentNewSection`.

Also, you're using the `findById` function and passing it your state, but a few lines lower you use that same function with a copy of your state. This makes me wonder if `findById` is mutating that variable. If it is, you should be making that copy sooner and using it for both calls to `findById` instead of passing the state directly.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The currentNewSection is an object in newSections. And I try to add an object to currentNewSection.data. I copied the state into currentNewSection. That is why I returned that.

findById is just a function that searches for an object in an array, I copied it in a comment under the question.